# Writing a limit so that the subscript goes directly underneath

Tags: spacing, subscripts

When I write `$\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = q$`,  the subscript `x \rightarrow p` appears to the right of the limit, instead of directly underneath it.

When I try `$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = q$`, the subscript of the limit takes up extra space, making the line taller than usual and creating an awkward extra space underneath everything else...

Is there a way to write limits in-line with the subscript underneath, and everything squished to the normal height of the line its in?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way would be to use `\scalebox` from [the `graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) to rescale the version obtained by `\displaystyle`. Here is a comparison of the usual inline version of `\lim` and the scaled version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Text}{\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet }

\newcommand{\Lim}[1]{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\displaystyle \lim_{#1}\;$}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\Text 
$\textcolor{blue}{\lim_{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = q}$
\Text
$\textcolor{red}{\Lim{x \rightarrow p} f(x) = q}$
\Text 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be easy to turn this into a macro which I can use every time I write a limit?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Updated solution to use macro version.

Comment: One might ask which one is worse: enlarging the interline spacing or printing an ugly symbol. I'll keep with the standard TeX way of typesetting the limit. :)

Comment: Why not using \limits? ```\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}``` does the job for me.

Comment: @Rusca8:  That is same as mifortin's solution. But, a requirement the OP had was "everything squished to the normal height of the line its in".

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise the ```\limits``` command extends the text downward

Answer (score 58):

I have used the following which puts x -> y under the limit.

```
\lim\limits_{x \to y}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer from a TeXnical point of view, but the typographical result is a disaster.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Isn't it `\limits` btw?

Comment: @egreg From the typographical point of view, the fact that `lim` and `f(x)` are not on the same line in the accepted answer, is a disaster as well!

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure if this is squished enough for you but the `amsmath` package allows you to put something under something else through the `\underset` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\underset{x \to \infty}{\lim}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this has the same problem as with the `\displaymode` solution--the limit with its superscript becomes taller than anything else on that line, adding extra margin space beneath the whole line.

Comment: Sorry. Actually, the `amsmath` documentation explains (pg 20) that's why subscripts are placed to the side. I just change my default spacing between lines so it doesn't look bad.