# My limits are moved

Tags: formatting, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a limit so that the subscript goes directly underneath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39390/writing-a-limit-so-that-the-subscript-goes-directly-underneath)

I am not sure how to explain this, but my code doesn't behave

```
      $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} xy + y$
```

Basically the {(x,y)\to(0,0)} part isn't under the limit operator, it's beside it.

Comment: This is the default behaviour in in-line math (between `$ ... $`). If you want to force display math, then use `$\displaystyle ...$`. However, this influences the line height and doesn't look right.

Comment: Duplicate: [Writing a limit so that the subscript goes directly underneath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39390/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are in inline, that is how it is done. If you want limits under, you can use `\limits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} xy + y$
$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} xy + y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about that trick.  It'll come in handy I'm sure.

Comment: Why do I have to put \lim in front of \limits?

Comment: How come it doesn't work here http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: Works fine for me there.  Did you include the $...$'s?