# Placing symbols under a text word

Tags: formatting, subscripts

I want to place a limit under a word, as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39390/writing-a-limit-so-that-the-subscript-goes-directly-underneath) except with an arbitrary text rather than an existing math operator like lim or max.

`\mathop{avg}\limits_{y\in U(x)}` gives me the following, but I would like "avg" to be in non-italicized.

[image]

I have also tried to define `\def\avg{\text{avg}}` and `\newcommand{\avg}{\text{avg}}`
but then the subscript is no longer underneath the text, even with `\avg\limits_{y\in U(x)}`:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: `\text` does not do what you think here. (a) it switches to the current text font, (b) if that font shape is italic the output of `\text` is italic. This is sadly a very common error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\avg{\mathop{\operator@font avg}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\avg_{y\in U(x)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

IIRC this was recommended by Herbert Voß in one of his books (credit where credit is due).

Comment: +1: Is `\operator@font` something "new"? I don't remember to have seen it before :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I couldn't tell you how old it is exactly, but it must have been around for at least a few years. EDIT: just checked, there are mentions of it going back to *at least* 1999, so yeah --- a few years, indeed!

Comment: Thank you! Is "\operator@font" a typo? i used simply \operatorfont and it worked.

Comment: @900edges Not a typo, no. Many internal LaTeX commands have `@` signs in them, which is also why the above snippet wrapped the definition in `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`: otherwise `@` would not be recognized as part of a command name.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No, it's not new, but this method is certainly not the best: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\avg}{avg}` is the way to go.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the reply! `\DeclareMathOperator` is at least what I learned from reading books when I started to learn LaTeX :).

Comment: @chsk ah somehow I missed the first comment, duh... so what exactly does the ```@``` do? ```\operatorfont``` did the job for me

Comment: @900edges it doesn't do anything as such, on its own; it's simply part of the command name of this internal command.

Comment: @chsk but it does something different from ```\operatorfont``` ?

Comment: @900edges having dug a little, it seems that `\operatorfont` is not defined by LaTeX, but `amsmath` does define it (specifically, `amsopn`) as a synonym for `\operator@font`. So if you're using `amsmath`, they're different commands that ultimately do the same thing. If you're not, only `\operator@font` is defined.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\underset`....

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \underset{y\in U(x)}{\mathrm{avg}} f(y)
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]